# Bash making loop to repeat code multiple times

Tags: bash, loops

I have a file called list_of_files.txt which is a list of over 500 other files. It looks like so:

```
list1.txt
list2.txt
list3.txt
etc
```

This lists all look like so: (all columns are made of numerical values)
    value1 value2 value3
    value4 value5 value6
    etc

For each of those lists, I want to cut a certain column of interest, sort it so that number are in increasing order and check whether my original file and new one have the same order.

I tried making a loop .sh script like so:

```
for i in list_of_files.txt
do
cut -f3 -d " " list*.txt > chr*_all_positions.txt
sort -n chr*_all_positions.txt > chr*_ordered_positions.txt
diff chr*_all_positions.txt chr*_ordered_positions.txt > result_*.txt
done
```

However, this does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the numbers, not the file names:

```
i=1
while [[ -f list$i.txt ]] ; do
    cut -f3 -d " " list$i.txt > chr$i\_all_positions.txt
    sort -n chr$i\_all_positions.txt > chr$i\_ordered_positions.txt
    diff chr$i\_all_positions.txt chr$i\_ordered_positions.txt > result_$i.txt
    ((i++))
done
```

Also, you can use `sort -c` or `sort -C` to check whether the output is sorted without the need to create the `_ordered` file.

Comment: Thanks! This works. However, if my list files were named like so: list1.1.txt,  list1.2.txt, etc

Would this code still work? It doesn't seem to when I try.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to Bash. I tried adjusting by writing i=1.1 but I got an error.

Comment: I tried use i=1.1 or i=seq(1.1 1.2 1.3) but none of these work. From what I understand, it seems bash does not like using float numbers in while loops?

Comment: @m93: bash doesn't understand floats. use `1.$i` or loop over two variables and use `$i.$j` if you need to go to 2.1, 2.2, 3.1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using readarray and array

```
readarray -t arrname < list_of_files.txt

for filename in "${arrname[@]}"; do
    ...
done
```

Using read builtin

```
while read filename; do
    ...
done < list_of_files.txt
```